# Agrupar um campo data em meses

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Boa tarde, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Como eu posso colocar esta query para exibir de Janeiro a dezembro corretamente?

```
SELECT   
EMPRESA,ATIVIDADE,DATA,STATUS
FROM tbl_atividades
WHERE YEAR(dt_vencimento) = '2019'
GROUP BY empresas, tipo_atividade
```

Resultado esperado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei também da seguinte forma entretanto o resultado foi que nao retorna os meses no mes a mes, pega o ultimo registro que ele encontra, e se eu jogo os meses no group by , ele cria varias atividades a mais.

```
SELECT   
empresas,
tipo_atividade,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=1) mes1,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=2) mes2,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=3) mes3,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=4) mes4,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=5) mes5,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=6) mes6,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=7) mes7,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=8) mes8,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=9) mes9,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=10) mes10,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=11) mes11,
(SELECT STATUS WHERE MONTH(dt_vencimento)=12) mes12
FROM 
tbl_atividades
WHERE 
YEAR(dt_vencimento) = '2019'
GROUP BY 
empresas,tipo_atividade
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza que tem o status dos 12 meses para todas empresas? Em vista sua query está correta, ou dependendo de como usa esses registro, seu `GROUP BY` está causando o erro. Porque o estranho é vir `NULL`. Se fosse algo de vir errado, seria data/ordenação/limit. Se puder, coloca um exemplo no sqlfiddle ou db-fiddle.

Comment: Posta seu código completo aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: https://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/vendas-mes/1332229/      pivot com case